# Unable to get correct output from tsv file using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, spyder

I have a tsv file which I am trying to read by the help of pandas. The first two rows of the files are of no use and needs to be ignored. Although, when I get the output, I get it in the form of two columns. The name of the first column is Index and the name of second column is a random row from the csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('zahlen.csv', sep='\t', skiprows=2)
```

Please refer to the screenshot below.
[image]

The second column name is in bold black, which is one of the row from the file. Moreover, using '\t' as delimiter does not separate the values in different column. I am using Spyder IDE for this. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I think you need a header=None as an argument in read_csv

Comment: Thank you @djk47463. Using header=None removed the row from column name, but still the values are not splitting in different columns. Do I need to explicitly split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = pd.read_table('zahlen.csv', header=None, skiprows=2)
```

`read_table()` is more suited for tsv files and `read_csv()` is a more specialized version of it. Then `header=None` will make first row data, instead of header.

Comment: With the above code, I am just getting a single column as output with no header.

Comment: are you sure that you have Tabs as separators? can you add `sep='\s+'` to `read_table()` above and see what happens?

Comment: No change with adding sep. I am also not very sure about the separation character in the file, but till now I have tried '\t', '<space>' and '\s+'. All three unfortunately return the same result.

Comment: Without inspecting the file it is hard to come up with anything reasonable. If you have ability to share the file somehow (e.g. Dropbox), I would be able to look into it. Or you can print it out to console and paste it here.

Comment: Please find the file at the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByLV3kGjFP_zZWRjMWJzSTdMLVU/view?usp=sharing.
Let me know in case if it cannot be accessed.

Comment: Yep, me too. With `pd.read_table('zahlen.csv', skiprows=1, header=0)` I even get proper column names: `Verteilung 1` through `Verteilung 50`.

Comment: I also tried to include the header column Verteilung 1 through Verteilung 50, and it worked. Why when I was skipping the header row as well, I was only getting a single column as output, any idea!

Comment: So this time I tried `data = pd.read_table('zahlen.csv', header=None, skiprows=2)` and it worked perfect, as I expected. Thank you for the help :)